# Fetching data from flask API

Tags: flutter, dart, flask

When I use the **emulator** I use this one
`http://10.0.2.2:5000`
and all is good

When I use the **real device** I have a problem

I'm trying to use this
`http://127.0.0.1:5000`
but it's not working I don't know why.

> flask file

```
from flask import Flask, request, json
from flask.json import jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/temp', methods = ['GET'])
def temp_Klevin_to_celsius():
    zipcode=str(request.args['zipcode'])
    r=requests.get(
        'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='+zipcode+',us&appid=5e50d7b5ffd8f7551ac8e526bff04a8d')
    json_object=r.json()
    temp_k=json_object['main']['temp']
    result=round((temp_k-273.15),2)
    d={}
    d['zipcode']=str(result)
    return d

@app.route('/convert', methods = ['GET'])
def convert_currency():    
    from_currency = str(request.args['from_currency']).upper()
    to_currency = str(request.args['to_currency']).upper()
    amount = float(request.args['amount'])       
    response = requests.get(
        f"https://api.frankfurter.app/latest?amount={amount}&from={from_currency}&to={to_currency}")
    d={}
    d['curr']=str(response.json()['rates'][to_currency])
    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> function file

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

fetchdata(String url)async
{
  http.Response response =await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  return response.body;
}
```

currency file

```
import 'dart:convert';


import 'package:boombest_driver/pages/function.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CurrencyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrencyPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CurrencyPage> createState() => _CurrencyPageState();
}

class _CurrencyPageState extends State<CurrencyPage> {
  String url='',fromCurrency='',toCurrency='',amount='';
  var data;
  String output='';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Currency Converter')),
      body: Center(child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [  

              TextField(
                      onChanged: (value){
                        fromCurrency=value.toString();                
                      },                      
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Convert from",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                        ),

                      ),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),

                    ),
              const SizedBox(height: 22,),                    

              TextField(
                      onChanged: (value){
                        toCurrency=value.toString();                
                      },                      
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Convert To",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                        ),

                      ),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),

                    ),
              const SizedBox(height: 22,),                    

              TextField(
                      onChanged: (value){
                        amount=value.toString();                
                      },                      
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Amount",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                        ),

                      ),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),

                    ),
              const SizedBox(height: 22,),                    
              
            TextButton(onPressed: ()async{
              if(fromCurrency!='' && toCurrency!='' && amount!=''){
                url = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/convert?from_currency='+fromCurrency+'&to_currency='+toCurrency+'&amount='+amount;
                // url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/convert?from_currency='+fromCurrency+'&to_currency='+toCurrency+'&amount='+amount;
                
                data = await fetchdata(url);
                var decoded = jsonDecode(data);
                setState(() {
                  output = amount+' '+fromCurrency+' is equal to '+decoded['curr']+' '+toCurrency;
                  
                });
              }else{
                setState(() {
                  output = "Please Enter a valid data";
                });
              }
      
            }, child: const Text(
              'Convert',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            )),
            
            Text(output,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.green))
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

**How** I can solve this problem to make it work on a **real device**?

**update: the problem is solved**

**thank you all**

firstly press `win + R`

then open `Settings`
chose `Network & Internet`
then press `Wi-Fi`

then press on your Wi-Fi network
for example
[press on Barada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILVx4.png)

then change it to private
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x08Mq.png)

in the flask file

> instead of this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> put this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.1.5', port=5000, debug=True, threaded=False)
```

How I can get this `192.168.1.5`

Open Cmd -> enter "ipconfig" -> you'll get

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : aaa::bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeeee
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 555.666.777.888
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 351.153.351.353
```

So you will have the  `IPv4 Address`

in the currency file

I replaced this line

```
url = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/convert?from_currency='+fromCurrency+'&to_currency='+toCurrency+'&amount='+amount;
```

with this line

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.5:5000/convert?from_currency='+fromCurrency+'&to_currency='+toCurrency+'&amount='+amount;
```

in the currency file

I replaced this line
url = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/temp?zipcode='+zipCode;

with this line

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.5:5000/temp?zipcode='+zipCode;
```

Comment: Without code nobody could Help ;)

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is **localhost**, your computer, this means that you can only reach it in your computer.

So, in your phone which is a **different** device, **that IP won't work!** You need to use your Ipv4.

If you're running Windows, you can get your ip with the following steps;

Cmd -> enter "ipconfig" -> you'll get

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : aaa::bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeeee
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 111.222.333.444
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 555.666.777.888
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 351.153.351.353
```

you should use : `http://111.222.333.444:5000`

Comment: I try that, it's not working

Comment: Are you sure it's IPv4 Address?

Comment: Yes. You need to have your pc and device on the same network. Also check if the port 5555 is opened on your firewall!

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved the problem, and you can see how I did it in the question.

Comment: @NoureddinSameer Nice! Congrats!